# Android animate drawable End of textview

Tags: android, animation

i have this textview

```
 <Textview
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/notification_bar_drwable"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_sharcol"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
```

and i need to animate just the drawable End

like this

```
messageText.animate().alpha(0.2f).setDuration(500).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

this code is animate the textview ,,, but i need to animate just the end drawable  ! any idea ??

Comment: You can use the `combination of textView and an imageView into a relativeLayout` and then just `animate the imageView`

Comment: You can add animation for views only.

Comment: i tried this but when textview  lines or text is increase ,, the image not appear ! so i use drawable end

Comment: Then make a linear layout.

Comment: i tried many time and i decide to add end drawable as a solution

Comment: Use `AnimationDrawable` . Or a `Relativelayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView` will be a better solution .

Comment: hey , try this animated vector - https://mayojava.github.io/android/animated-vector-drawable-xml-bundle/

Answer (score 0):

you may try this way using Imageview

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Textview
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_sharcol"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawable_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/notification_bar_drwable"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

and try to use animation on `imageView` with  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281246/animate-imageview-from-alpha-0-to-1)

Comment: but i cannot add fixed android:layout_weight to textview or image i need image view next to textview with wrap content !

Comment: okay then you need to change  ----android:layout_width="wrap_content"--- in LinearLayout

Comment: not working as i need !

Comment: can you please explain your issue in detail with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it several times to understand what you mean.you can like this,I'm different above :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:textColor="@color/app_color_sharcol"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawable_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_bar_drwable"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think this is you want,you can try it. Hope help you